# Heroku, Error with deployment Agora appbuilder. "Over 5 project limit." But I don't have 5 projects

Tags: heroku

When I'm trying to deploy project at https://appbuilder.agora.io/ with Heroku it creates a new empty project but then I got this error:
"Over 5 project limit. You have too many Heroku projects. Please delete older projects or upgrade your plan".
Even if I have 0 projects.

I'm even paid for the service, but still not working.

Any help please

Expected to not have any errors

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [we literally cannot help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577). Contact Heroku and / or Agora support.

Comment: It's nice to say "to contact Heroku support", but they redirect me here to 
"Engage with a community of passionate experts to get the answers you need" and give the link to the Stack Overflow with it's tag

Comment: They can say whatever they want, but they don't get to decide what's on topic here. Again, we _literally cannot help_. If you're a paying customer, you should be able to submit a help ticket.